# Python Requests Cannot Find Connection Adapters

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-3.4

When I run the following code in Python3.4 on Windows8.1:

```
r = requests.get(url)
```

It returns, among other things:

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 644, in get_adapter
   raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url) requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '"http://example.com"'
```

Is this simply a problem with my code, my firewall or something else entirely? How would I go about fixing it?

Comment: it's a problem with your url i guess, the url supposed to be like this - "http://example.com", not like this '"http://example.com"'

Comment: @minitoto you mean without quotes? Could be, let me check.

Comment: @minitoto Yup, that was it (I'd implemented input() improperly somewhere). Thanks!

Comment: I faced the same message when I used `'localhost:5000'` instead of `'http://localhost:5000'`. In other words, the message seems to be related to `requests` not finding a proper protocol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change your get request to use only one type of quotes:

```
requests.get("http://example.com")
```

you are trying to do it with two types of quotes at the same time and it gives a proper error:

```
requests.get('"http://example.com"')
```